# Binary searching a decreasing list?

Tags: c++, arrays, search, iterator

I have an array sorted in strictly decreasing order and an element `val`; i want to **find the index of largest element in the array which is less than val**(or equal if val already exists there) and i want to do so in `logn` time. And reversing the array and doing upper_bound() is not an option.

Eg. if array is {10,5,3,1} and val is 6, the function should return 1.

I am really new to iterators and tried something like adding a comparison function in upper_bound() to make it work but it failed. How should I go about this.

Note: I checked for similar questions prior to posting and found one but unfortunately it pertained to Java, so.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) page example not helping ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `upper_bound` with the proper comparison function:

- Your list is reversed (`upper_bound` usually expects increasing order) so you need to use `>` rather than `<`.
- You want to include the searched element (while `upper_bound` usually excludes it) so you need to use `>=` rather than mere `>`.

.

```
int data[] = {10,5,3,1};
auto item = std::upper_bound(std::begin(data), std::end(data), 6,
                             [](int a, int b) { return a >= b; });
```

Now you only have to convert the resulting iterator to an index (after checking it is valid):

```
if (item != std::end(data)) {
    auto index = std::distance(std::begin(data), item);
    std::cout << index << std::endl;
}
else
    std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
```

Comment: You may consider using `rbegin()` and `rend()` and belaying the customer comparator. (pretty sure that would work anyway; haven't tried it but it pencils).

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed this would work with a proper container that provides `rbegin/rend` but with a legacy array I'm not sure how to correctly obtain a `reverse_iterator` pair (there has to be a way though).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `upper_bound()` that takes a compare function as it's forth arg.

Answer (score 0):

For the iteration way, what I would probably do is start my search `val` values from the end of the array. ie:

```
int indexFinder(int array[], int arraySize, int val){
    for(int i = (val >= arraySize ? 0 : (arraySize - val)); i < arraySize; ++i){
        if(array[i] <= val) return i;
    }
}
```

One key to this loop is that once it encounters any value less than or equal to, it return the index, limiting it to the first case it finds.

It also checks to see if `val` is larger than the largest array index.